# Kalman Filter in Vision - Constant Velocity Model - Units

Tags: image-processing, kalman-filters

Let's assume we have series of frames with a known object. I want to track the object using Kalman filter using constant velocity / acceleration models. My questions are:

1. Which model to use? CV or CA?
2. If I use CV, how to calculate velocity of object? and what is the unit of velocity? pixels/sec or m/s?
3. If I use CA, how do we evaluate velocity and acceleration of the object?
4. If object moves closer to camera, it drastically shifts in both  and y pixels. How do we accommodate this change? CV and CA models fail.

Comment: You probably need to combine it with computer vision. If applying computer vision to the entire frame is too expensive you might be able to use the prediction step of the Kalman filter as the first guess for the computer vision.

Comment: What's your motion model ? Do you use 3D world coordinates or 2D projection coordinates ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Depends on the properties of the tracked object.
2. pixels / frame. You may convert to time units by the FPS.
3. The model will estimate those given the detection per frames.
4. You may use angle based models. They may require additional measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use constant velocity, constant acceleration, or some other model depends on what you know about the behavior of the target, and on what you need out of the tracker.

In a lot of tracking applications you can't know for sure what the target is going to do -- in that case, you need to guess, or find the model that works best for the highest number of scenarios *that you intend to address*.

Calculation of the velocity, or velocity + acceleration, of the object gets baked into the Kalman filter.  To calculate velocity, model your object's motion as
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix} &=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix} + u(t) \\
y &= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ \dot x\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
 \tag 1$$

To calculate acceleration, model the object's motion as
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ \dot x \\ \ddot x\end{bmatrix} &=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ \dot x \\ \ddot x\end{bmatrix} + u(t) \\
y &= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ \dot x \\ \ddot x \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
 \tag 2$$

With the proper motion model, the Kalman filter will take care of the rest.

If you have a 2D image and you're trying to account for object motion toward or away from the imager -- good luck, this is not an easy problem.  You can either ignore the problem and treat the tracking as a 2D problem, or you can attempt to do some sort of computer vision exercise where you're estimating range using the size of the object you're tracking.

If you go down that computer vision rabbit hole -- there will be plenty of papers out there that you can read, and attempt to use.